# How to do a round railing/ fence

Tags: modeling

I am a very beginner in Blender. I am modelling a tank and want to make a round railing at the top of the tank and a ladder.

The ladder should be no problem, but what is the easiest way to make a round railing with the same curve as my tank?

Here is a photo of the tank:

[image: tank] [image: tankMesh]

I am not asking for a whole solution, just some tips, since I notice there are lots of features, that makes things easy in blender, but I don't know them at the moment :(...

Comment: Could you add example of how it should look like?

Comment: Something like http://www.teatucson.com/images/railing_on_one_tank_with_guy_cropped.jpg   or like http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/f3676bd5d2dc45de9d4784e629b80d42/concrete-cylindrical-industrial-silo-with-metal-stairs-with-safety-j8mjxd.jpg

Comment: I am wondering first how to decide if it should be a "separate object" i.e I model the ladder and railing and "paste it" to the tank or if I should use extrude etc to model them from the tank....hope you understand what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following steps

1. Please select the set of edges on the top of your tank, using Alt + click on the edge as show in image below:
   [image]
2. Hit Shift + D to duplicate edges
3. Hit p to seperate the edges
4. Go to the object mode and you will get a duplicate in outliner
5. Go to edit mode - Select edges using Alt + click
6. Extrude a twice as shown in the picture below:
   [image]
7. Select alternative faces and hit X and delete **Only Faces**

You can do it as a single obect too, I hope it help you